# Calculator digits recognition

Tags: ocr, calculator, digit

I have to recognize set of digits on something like scoreboard, calculator and similiar devices display.

[image: Calculator display]

I tried that image in most popular ocr's, but with no success.

How can i preprocess this image to get it work with ocr frameworks? How to get that digits from there?

Answer (score 0):

First,Based on edge detection, determine the position of the digits. Then, convert the image to a two-value image (white foreground and black background). Last, put it to OCR...